# “Cannot read property 'client' of undefined” angularJS with SignalR

Tags: .net, angularjs, signalr

i am new to signalR. what i am doing is creating a simple app which add name to db and display to client but i am getting an error "Cannot read property 'client' of undefined"
here is my angularJS code

```
     myApp.controller('firstController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.saveName = function () {
        $http.post("/Name/saveName/", { userName: $scope.name }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.loadNames();
        })
    }
    $scope.loadNames = function () {
        $http.get("/Name/getName/").then(function (response) {
            $scope.nameList = response.data;
        })
    }
    $scope.loadNames();
    $scope.hub = $.connection.myHub;
    $scope.notify = function () {
        $scope.hub.client.UserAddHub = function (name) {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.nameList.push(name);
            })
        }
        $.connection.hub.start();
    }
    $scope.notify();
});
```

this is what i write on server side

```
    private static IHubContext userHubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
operations op = new operations();
        op.save(userName);
        userHubContext.Clients.All.UserAddHub(userName);
```

and this is my hubclass

```
[HubName("myHub")]
public class MyHub : Hub
{

}
```

Am i missing something. Any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: After your $scope.loadNames() line, add a console.log() in to see what (if anything) is populating $scope.nameList

Comment: this is what i am getting in console  angular.js:14328 TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined
    at ChildScope.$scope.notify (myScript.js:20)

Comment: don't know much about SignalR but your $scope.hub is null for sure don't waste your time by looking at " client".May be $.connection.myHub is not working properly.If you wana check it just write $scope.hub={}; then it will say UserAddHub  is undef

Comment: i just added #scope.hub={}; but the error is same.. TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using external script to load signalR, make sure in your Layout.cshtml (or any other layouts your are using), you have added this reference

```
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

just after adding signalR. There seems to be nothing wrong with the code and all I can see is your hub is null.

**Edit:** For future readers, double check that you have also added `app.MapSignalR();` to your Startup.cs class.

Comment: i added <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script> but now its throwing another error.. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Which resource? Go to your browser and look for http://localhost:/signalr/hubs and CTRL+F the word "myHub", you should see it there.

Comment: http://localhost:port/signalr/hubs what I mean was the address you are running the app on. Add the port too

Comment: ok i got a clue from your answer and add app.MapSignalR(); to my startup.cs . plus i havent added the <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>. the error is removed. Thanks bro.

Answer (score -1):

After your $scope.hub line add:

```
$scope.hub.client = {};
```

Also noticed that you call $.connection.myHub; then later on you call the start() method on $.connection.hub ... Should that be $.connection.myHub.start(); or should it be $scope.hub.start(); ?